# 1004 Error - Dynamically Assigning Formula to a Range of Cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, range, formula

I am trying to dynamically set the cell that a formula is entered in when my macro is executed.  This block of code will be looped through about 10 times, each with a new section of employees. Ordered by department. So as the loop comes back to this point the first cell will change.

I get this error:

> Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Here is my code:

```
'Select the top cell in the "%Working" Column

Range(Cells(StartTemp, 9)).Select

'Insert the Formula - Billable/(Billable + Unbillable) * 100 into Column I for each section
'Formula is 'C4/(C4+C5)*100

Range(Cells(StartTemp, 9)).Formula = "=RC[-6]/(RC[-6]+RC[-5]) *100" 
Range(Cells(StartTemp, 9)).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00%"

'Insert the Formula into all cells in the section for this group.

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(StartTemp, 9), Cells(EndTemp, 9)), Type:=xlFillDefault    

Range(Cells(StartTemp, 9), Cells(EndTemp, 9)).Select
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which line is it that throws the error?

Comment: And what is the text of the error message?  (1004 has at least two different ones).

Answer (score 4):

You are getting that error because you are using `Range(Cells(StartTemp, 9))`

When using `Range` with `Cells` you cannot use just one cell. The syntax is

***Range(Cell1,Cell2)***

[image]

This will give you an error that you are getting :)

```
Msgbox Range(Cells(1, 1)).Address
```

[image]

Also avoid the use of `.Select`. They are also a major cause of errors.

Change your code to this and try it again (**UNTESTED**)

```
With Cells(StartTemp, 9)
    .Formula = "=RC[-6]/(RC[-6]+RC[-5]) * 100"
    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(StartTemp, 9), Cells(EndTemp, 9)), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With
```

Now try it.

Comment: +1 nice explanation Sidd as always.  @JasonR, You can get rid of the autofill too:  `With Range(Cells(StartTemp, 9), Cells(EndTemp, 9))
    .Formula = "=RC[-6]/(RC[-6]+RC[-5]) * 100"
    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
End With`

Comment: Thanks Sam. :) I remember you had suggested this last time as well. It skipped my mind this time. Now every time I see an Autofill, I will think of you :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks everyone for your input. I've made the tweaks and its working great for me now. Thanks again!

Comment: @JasonR: Do remember to close the question by selecting the relevant post as answer :)