# For loop to change formula in relation to range excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

Wow, I feel like I'm really close on this one.

I have this code in a module:

```
Range("R1400").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1400, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1401").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1401, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1402").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1402, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1403").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1403, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1404").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1404, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1405").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1405, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1406").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1406, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1407").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1407, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1408").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1408, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1409").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1409, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1410").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1410, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1411").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1411, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1412").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1412, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1413").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1413, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1414").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1414, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1415").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1415, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1416").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1416, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1417").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1417, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1418").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1418, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1419").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1419, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1420").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1420, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1421").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1421, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1422").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1422, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1423").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1423, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1424").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1424, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1425").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1425, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1426").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1426, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1427").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1427, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1428").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1428, 0))+0.0625"
Range("R1429").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1429, 0))+0.0625"
```

Now, let me be clear, this code works as I'd like it to. It might be obvious that I'm taking a range of numbers in one column, rounding them all to the nearest whole integer, then adding a sixteenth, and representing those values in a different column.

*however*

I feel like this could be 'better' executed in less code, and I'd like to become a more efficient programmer, so I try to write it like so:

```
Dim X As Integer
For X = 1400 To 1429
    Range("R" & X).Formula = "=(ROUND(""AC"" "&X", 0))+0.0625"
Next X
```

But this (and the variations I've tried) all throw '1004' errors or syntax errors. Most of the changes I've made have had to do with the quotation marks and their placement, and then I've also tried to implement advice from these questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094996/1004-error-dynamically-assigning-formula-to-a-range-of-cells), [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472958/run-time-error-1004-using-range-in-a-for-loop-vba-excel-mac) [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787564/excel-vba-setting-cell-value-to-a-formula?lq=1) [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420748/change-cell-value-based-on-adjacent-cell-value) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646042/how-to-get-formulas-in-to-a-for-loop), but none of them seem to offer quite the solution that I'm looking for, or they don't make sense to me in my inexperience.

It's possible (likely) that my searches haven't contained the proper verbiage I'm looking for, but that's probably because I'm just now taking my first stab at VBA with this :)

Thanks for any help or references. This is my 1st question on StackOverflow, but you folks have definitely taught me darn near everything I know about coding to date.

Comment: you don't need loop. Use this one instead: `Range("R1400:R1429").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1400, 0))+0.0625"`. Btw, error occurs because you've missed `&` after `X` and you don't need quotes around `AC`: `"=(ROUND(AC" & X & ", 0))+0.0625"`

Comment: just to explain Simoco's excellent solution: VBA can apply a single formula to a whole range of cells in one operation. When it does so, just like in normal Excel when you copy one formula down cells, it varies the formula depending on which bits of the reference are fixed with the "$" signs and which bits are not (e.g. copying "=SUM($A$2:$D$2)" compared to copying "=SUM(A2:D2)". The top left cell is always the 'anchor' cell, so in the case suggested, assigning `AC1400` to a range is automatically adjusted appropriately to correspond to each row to mean `AC1401`, `AC1402` and etc...

Comment: @simoco, this is it, nixing the for loop was even more efficient than what I was going for. If you submit this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @Cor_Blimey, thanks for the clarification. I'll upvote when I get the clearance. This is the sort of response that kindly lays it out for future learners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments above, you don't need loop, you can simply use:

```
Range("R1400:R1429").Formula = "=(ROUND(AC1400, 0))+0.0625"
```

Excel would adjust formula properly for each row, so you would have:

- in `R1400` formula `=(ROUND(AC1400, 0))+0.0625`
- in `R1401` formula `=(ROUND(AC1401, 0))+0.0625`
- .....
- in `R1429` formula `=(ROUND(AC1429, 0))+0.0625`

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the `X` value in the `Range` function as a string. And you can pass the value of the referenced cell directly to `ROUND` using the same technique, rather than passing the cell reference. I don't know if that's an improvement, but it was my first instinct.

```
Range("R" & CStr(X)).Formula = "=(ROUND(" & Range("AC" & CStr(X)).Value & ", 0))+0.0625"
```

As @simoco has pointed out, you don't have to use the loop at all. But if you still wanted to, or run into similar problems in the future, the above should work.

Comment: you're helping prove the worth of this site. This is great to know. As with above, I'll upvote when I get clearance.